# Relative sizes of prime gaps

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

There are no prime numbers between the two primes $113$ and $127$.  That gap seems quite large by comparison to the sizes of the numbers in it.
$$
\frac{\text{size of gap}}{\text{prime just below the gap}} = \frac{14}{113} = 0.12389\ldots
$$
<s>**Is that the biggest that this particular statistic ever gets?**</s>

**Is that the last time this particular statistic ever gets that big?**

Comment: Are there restrictions on how big the gap has to be? i.e. $3$ and $5$ gives $2/3=.666...$

Comment: @MITjanitor I think he wants to find the smallest possible ratio.

Comment: @GitGud, even if he does, it goes to $0$. (Since $p_{k+1}/p_k \to 1$ as $k \to \infty$, the limit of $p_{k+1}/p_k - 1 \to 0$.)

Comment: @GitGud if he wants the smallest ratio then it'll get pretty small... look at 1979 and 1987 for instance (possibly infinitesimally small)

Comment: @MITjanitor biggest would probably gap between 2,3 which gives 1/2 = .5

Comment: oh right im an idiot :P

Comment: @MITjanitor : Clumsy of me; I've amended the question.

Comment: I can't speak to the answer, but for $n$ sufficiently large $g_n < p_n^\theta$ for some $\theta < 1$ (Hoheisel 1930). So the statistic in question is bounded above by $p_n^\theta / p_n$ which $ p_n^{\theta-1} $, which goes to $0$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$. This implies that there is a maximum.

Comment: It is the last time for at least the first million primes.

Comment: Assuming [this page](http://primes.utm.edu/notes/gaps.html) is reliable, the results in section 4 seem to indicate that it's the last time modulo a few that you can check by hand. See also [this](http://primes.utm.edu/notes/GapsTable.html)

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, the answer is positive. We have:

$$R_n := \frac{\text{size of gap}}{\text{prime just below the gap}} = \frac {p_{n+1} - p_n} {p_n} = \frac {p_{n+1}} {p_n} - 1$$

Using [some well known approximations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number) (Rosser's theorem) on $p_n$, we have

$$p_{n+1} \le (n+1) \log(n+1) + (n+1) \log \log(n+1)$$
$$p_n \ge n \log n + n \log \log n - n$$

So,

$$R_n + 1 \le \frac {n+1} n \frac {\log (n+1) + \log \log (n+1)} {\log n + \log \log n - 1}$$

RHS is a decreasing function, and so we have $R_n < 0.12389\ldots$ for all $n \ge 1296$. The remaining cases $31 \le n \le 1295$ may be checked manually.

Answer (score 2):

[Rohrbach and Weis](https://eudml.org/doc/150637) show that (as Martin notes in the comments):

$$ g_n < \frac{p_n}{13} \quad \quad n > 118$$

From this we have that your statistic is bounded by: $ \frac{1}{13} \approx 0.0769231 $ for $n > 118$. The 118th prime is $647$, and a quick numerical analysis verifies this.

Mathematica code to verify this (which should print nothing):

```
Do[If[Prime[k + 1]/Prime[k] - 1 >= 14/113, Print[k]], {k, 31, 119}]
```